# Кикает бота minecraft когда он пвп

Tags: node.js, бот, minecraft

Я сделал бота майнкрафт для пвп, когда он пвп и рядом нету предметов всё нормально но когда он убивает моба и из него что то выпадает бота сразу кикает (когда он не пвп его тоже кикает от предметов), ошибка:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Вторая ошибка (две разные ошибки):

```
Error: write ECONNRESET
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:931:11)
    at Socket._write (node:net:943:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at Framer.ondata (C:\Users\creep\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams\readable.js:662:22)
    at Framer.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at addChunk (C:\Users\creep\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\internal\streams\readable.js:278:12) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

Код:

```
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer")
const { pathfinder, Movements, goals: { GoalNear } } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder') 
const pvp = require('mineflayer-pvp').plugin
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
host: "ip",
port: "port",
version: "1.16.5",
username: "MineBot" }); 
bot.loadPlugin(pvp)  
bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)  
let target = null

bot.once('spawn', function () {
    setInterval(() => {  
        entity = bot.nearestEntity()  
        if (entity && entity.type === 'mob') {  
            const dist = bot.entity.position.distanceTo(entity.position)  
            if (dist > 5.0) {
                target = entity  
                const mcData = require('minecraft-data')(bot.version)  
                const movements = new Movements(bot, mcData)  
                movements.scafoldingBlocks = []  
                bot.pathfinder.setMovements(movements)  
                bot.pathfinder.setGoal(new GoalNear(entity.position.x, entity.position.y, entity.position.z, 1))  
            } else if (dist < 5.0) {
                target = null  
                bot.attack(entity, true)  
            }  
        }
    }) 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, в моём коде неправильно проверяло мобов и бот пытался атаковать предметы и стрелы, исправленный код:

```
const mineflayer = require("mineflayer")
const { pathfinder, Movements, goals: { GoalNear } } = require('mineflayer-pathfinder') 
const pvp = require('mineflayer-pvp').plugin
const bot = mineflayer.createBot({
host: "ip",
port: "port",
version: "1.16.5",
username: "MineBot" }); 
bot.loadPlugin(pvp)  
bot.loadPlugin(pathfinder)  
bot.once('spawn', function () {
            setInterval(() => {  
                entity = bot.nearestEntity() 
                if (entity) { 
                    if (entity.mobType === 'Zombie' || entity.mobType === 'Creeper' || entity.mobType === 'Phantom' || entity.mobType === 'Skeleton' || entity.mobType === 'Spider' || entity.mobType === 'Vex' || entity.mobType === 'Silverfish' || entity.mobType === 'Slime' || entity.mobType === 'Vindicator' || entity.mobType === 'Evoker' || entity.mobType === 'Witch' || entity.mobType === 'Stray' || entity.mobType === 'Husk' || entity.mobType === 'Ravager' || entity.mobType === 'Pillager' || entity.mobType === 'Endermite') {
                        bot.pvp.attack(entity)
                    } else {
                        bot.pvp.stop()
                    }
                } else {  
                    bot.pvp.stop()
                }  
            })  
    })
```